# Measuring orthogonal residuals with orthogonal regression (total least squares)

Tags: r, regression

I have a good understanding of orthogonal regression, but in modeling with orthogonal regression in R, I have run into some issues. I have been using the `onls` package. The function `resid_o` is supposed to measure the orthogonal residuals. However, the distances to not appear to meet my understanding.

```
> Book1
   ID    Y X     ortho
1   1   44 51 1.8562060
2   2   45 53 3.3313832
3   3   39 56 1.7323595
4   4   33 49 1.0961453
5   5   32 44 0.6067502
6   6   25 46 2.4314954
7   7   34 51 2.8150216
8   8   31 50 1.8991531
9   9   27 43 1.5226187
10 10   31 46 3.9516167
```

This is my data, with `ortho` being the orthogonal residuals measured by `resid_o`. However, when compared to the following plot, you can see my confusion as the lengths of `ortho` do not particularly correspond to the residuals.

[image]

**Where is my understanding of orthogonal residuals going wrong?**

EDIT:
Here is my code:

```
library(onls)
Book1 <- data.frame(x = c(51,53,56,49,44,46,51,50,43,46), y = c(44,45,39,33,32,25,34,31,27,31), ID = 1:10)
model.one <- lm(y ~ x, data = Book1)
summary(model.one)
model.two <- onls(y ~ b0 + b1*x, data = Book1, start = list(b0 = coef(model.one)[1], b1 = coef(model.one)[2]))
summary(model.two)

Book1$ortho <- residuals_o(model.two)
Book1$x0 <- x0(model.two)
Book1$y0 <- y0(model.two)

plot(model.two, fitted.nls = FALSE)
text(Book1$x, Book1$y, labels = Book1$ID)
```

Comment: Please explain how you have determined there is any discrepancy between the plot and the table you show.  (I cannot find one.)

Comment: @whuber check for ID #5 and #10 specifically. Shouldn't the orthogonal distance for 10 be far less than for 5?

Comment: Yes, I have been in the process of taking a closer look after I wrote that comment, and agree.  I would hypothesize that in constructing the table, the residuals were written in an incorrect order.  Could you describe exactly how you created that table?  The table also is missing some values that appear in the plot: what are the fitted coordinates? And there ought to be *two* residuals for each observation, one for each coordinate.

Comment: @whuber I edited my question with my code so you could see it. Should I be able to measure simply the orthogonal residual that the `onls` function is minimizing?

Comment: Your code does not seem to be reproducible: you use undefined variables `Book1$TS`, `Book1$X3pt`, and `Book1$ID` to annotate the plot--and the heart of the problem concerns whether these variables correctly match the variables `x` and `y` you used to create the models.

Comment: @whuber sorry was trying to simplify and forgot to fix those. Should be good now.

Comment: It's an `onls` problem.  It permutes its data!  To analyze the results reliably, create a new data frame using `x0`, `y0`, `model.two$pred`, and `model.two$resp`, as shown in `onls:::plot.onls`.

Comment: @whuber could you maybe show a quick example of what you mean?

Comment: You already posted a wonderful example!  The residuals are correct, but they are returned in the wrong order by `residuals_o`, `x0`, and `y0`.

Comment: @whuber ah, thank you!

Comment: Re-run your code with a simplest possible reproducible example: `Book1 <- data.frame(x=4:1, y=4:1, ID=1:4)`.  By comparing `x` with `x0`, you will immediately see the problem.